# How can I print the string "aaabbbccaa" as a3b3c2a2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compression

I am given a user entered string 'aaabbbccaa'. 
I want to find the duplicates and print the string back as 'a3b3c2a2'

Comment: What have you tried, what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with this way:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "aaabbbccaa"
# group by characters
groups = groupby(s)

# process result
result = "".join([label + str(len(list(group))) for label, group in groups])
print(result)
```

Output:

`a3b3c2a2`

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_string(source):
    new = ''
    while source:
        counter = 0
        first_char = source[0]
        while source and source[0] == first_char:
            counter += 1
            source = source[1:]
        new += f'{first_char}{counter}'
    return new

print(process_string('aaabbbccaa'))
'a3b3c2a2'
```

Answer (score 0):

this kind of solution could mabye solve it, it does what you specify, however if you are able to put it into your context, no idea :)

hope it helps!

```
c = 0
foo = "aaabbbccaa"
bar = ""
prev = None

for counter, index in enumerate(foo):
    print(c)
    if prev == None:

        print("first")


    elif prev == index:

        print("second") 
    elif prev != index:
        c = 0
    c += 1
    prev = index   
    try:
        if index in foo[counter+1]:
            print("third")
        else:
            print("fourth")
            bar += index + str(c)
    except:
        print("fifth")
        bar += index + str(c)


print("foo is {}".format(foo)) # will output aaabbbccaa
print("bar is {}".format(bar)) # will output a3b3c2a2
```

Comment: when i posted i saw that earlier answer by @Roomm is most likely waaay better instead of my crappy messy code :P